# Ajax call function in index file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem with calling Ajax function which one is declared in site.js file and I want to make call of this function index.html file. But when I try there is an error.

Site.js

```
$(function updateTable() {
$.ajax({
    url: '/HomeController/SendDataToTable',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        var tbody = $('#mytable tbody');
        tbody.empty();
        $.each(data, function (index, a) {
            var row = $('<tr>');
            row.append($('<td class="col-md-1">').text(a.Id));
            row.append($('<td class="col-md-1">').text(a.name));
            row.append($('<td class="col-md-1">').text(a.address));
            
            tbody.append(row);
        });
    }
});
```

This is the index.chtml file

```
@section Scripts{
<script>
    $(
        function () {
            updateTable(); // Populate Table initialy
            setInterval(function () {
                updateTable();
            }, 5000);
        });

</script>
```

I'm to make changes in Site.js file and tried to add script to Index.cshtml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function declaration will create a variable, in the current scope, with the same name as the function and assign the function to it.

A function expression (even a named function expression) will not.

You have a named function expression that you are passing as an argument to `$()`.

If you want it available as a variable so you can call it later, change it to a function declaration (and then pass it to `$()` separately).

```
function updateTable() { ... }
$(updateTable);
```

Comment: It will work automaticly asynchronous because is ajax or I must yet change something?